# How to Set the Selected Item in a UITabBar From within the Code?

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm implementing `UITabBar` in my app. I managed making it work by implementing `UITabBarDelegate` in my header file and using

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

in my `.m` file (as explained in [this tutorial](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2099944?start=0&tstart=0)).

Now, there are 3 scenarios in my app where I wish to set the selected `UITabBarItem` manually from within the code (and not based on user action):

- Upon `viewDidLoad`
- After `didReceiveMemoryWarning`
- In a certain case when the user is entering another view controller - when they get back, they should get back to a different tab than the one they clicked on.

Can anyone direct me to how this should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITabBarController` class has two properties for managing the selected tab, namely, `selectedViewController` and `selectedIndex`. Look into those in the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thanks for the reference, I did find my answer there - it was selectedItem property.

Comment: but what it the implemented controller is not a `UITabBarController`, what if i wanna use `UITabBar` and implement it delegate? and i wanna open the selected item view?