# Trigger UITabbarController Action from UIButton Touch

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a general tabbed application in Swift. I would like to be able to trigger an action on the tabbarcontroller from a UIButton Touch within one of the view controllers.

The button is located in View Controller 2 and should trigger a segue back to view Controller 1 via the UITabbarController when touched.

[image]

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/6806806/1219539

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

**use appropriate index for the tab you want to accesss